# MvvmCross Version 4 Custom Binding

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I have an app that has been running on MvvmCross 3 for about a year.  I decided to go for the update and use version 4.  I have worked through most of the issues, but I am hung up on the following error:

> 'MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.Construction.IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry'
>   does not contain a definition for 'RegisterCustomBindingFactory' and
>   no extension method 'RegisterCustomBindingFactory' accepting a first
>   argument of type
>   'MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.Construction.IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

In my Setup.cs I have this

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories(
    MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.Construction.IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
{
    base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
    registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<EditText>("FocusText",
        textView => new MvxEditTextFocusBinding(textView));
    registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<EditText>("FocusChange",
        editText => new MvxEditTextFocusChangeBinding(editText));
}
```

Is there a replacement for `RegisterCustomBindingFactory`?

Comment: Namespaces have changed. Make sure you are using the correct ones.

Comment: I did what is said to do here: https://mvvmcross.com/docs/upgrade-to-mvvmcross-40  Do you, by chance, know which namespace needs to be included for RegisterCustomBindingFactory to work?

Comment: @JimWilcox, the namespace you are using `MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.Construction` is right, but are you maybe missing it from your using statements as you are using the full qualified namespace with `IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry` method signature?  `RegisterCustomBindingFactory` is a extension method in this namespace.

Comment: @PlaceHold3r How did you change the markup so my errors above were highlighted?

Comment: @JimWilcox, it's the quotation formatting option, the one to the right of the link icon (left of braces) in the formatting toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PlaceHold3r was correct.  I hadn't included

```
using MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.Construction;
```

so the name space was missing.